# AWS API Gateway Execution Logs to ELK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Who has successfully parsed AWS execution logs to API Gateway, and how did they do that? I much prefer the Access Logs and that was rather trivial to setup but they are missing some information which I would like to log, such as some Response Headers.

Comment: You can attach a subscription filter to the Cloudwatch log group for the API Gateway stage.  This subscription filter can put the log entries onto a Kinesis Firehose, which can be configured to deliver them to Elasticsearch.  See documentation on ES [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-aws-integrations.html#es-aws-integrations-cloudwatch-es) and on Subscription Filters [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html)

Comment: I'm looking for more detail. I'm aware I can do all that but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if somebody has solved this before.